# How to import dynamic module within a sub directory

Tags: python

I am dynamically importing files/modules using `import_module`. When I had the files in the same directory this worked:

```py
importlib.import_module('child')
module.main()
```

However, when I reorganized my folder structure to look this:

```
- sub
  - child.py
- main.py
```

I assumed that I could do this:

```py
module = importlib.import_module('sub/child')
module.main()
```

But it gives me the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'child'

I tried the following paths as well:

- `/sub/child`
- `./sub/child`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) takes a module name, not a file path, as an argument. This means you must use `.` not `/`:

```
module = importlib.import_module('sub.child')
```

Comment: Ahh okay. That fixes it, and the `__init__.py` wasn't needed for me